# Pub/sub push subscription from an endpoint API URL

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on pubsub subscription in my application. I want to know how to code for push  subscription in python through a end point.

here is the code which i tried:

```
> from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

> from google.oauth2 import service_account


> gcp_service_account_credential_path = 'gcp-service-account.json'


>credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(str(gcp_service_account_credential_path))

> project_id = "my project name"

> topic_name = 'topic name'

> subscription_name = 'sub name'

> endpoint = 'http://localhost:5059/push_pub_sub_data'




> subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials)

> topic_path = subscriber.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

>subscription_path=subscriber.subscription_path(project_id,subscription_name)

> push_config = {'push_endpoint': endpoint}

> subscriber.modify_push_config(subscription_path, push_config)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you please give more details? and what have you tried up until now?

Comment: i search in google but i didn't find any source properly related to this push mechanism.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are conflating [push subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) and [pull subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull). Push subscriptions would typically not use the Cloud Pub/Sub client library; one would use this library when trying to pull messages from a subscription. You would only call `modify_push_config` if you are trying to change an existing subscription from a pull subscription into a push subscription. If you know from the beginning that you want to use a push subscription, then you should select that option in the Cloud console when you create a subscription:

[image: Cloud console subscription creation]

or specify the endpoint when creating the subscription:

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions create <subscription name> --topic <topic name> --push-endpoint <URL to push to>`

You will need to [register the push endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#other-endpoints). Note this means that localhost won't work as a push endpoint. Additionally, the push endpoint needs to be HTTPS, not HTTP.

Once you have the push endpoint created, then you need to configure something at that endpoint to receive HTTP POST requests. This is not something that is Pub/Sub specific; you can use whatever Python library you want that sets up an HTTPS endpoint. Python ships with [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), which can do this, though it should probably only be used for experimenting and not deployed as a fully secure production solution. The [messages you will receive](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receive_push) are JSON-encoded Pub/Sub messages, e.g.,

```
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
    "messageId": "136969346945"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

You use the HTTP response code to ack or nack the message. The codes 200, 201, 202, 204, or 102 all indicate successful processing and any other code indicates that the message should be redelivered.

Comment: how can we get the endpoint url while creating a push type subscription? and also do we need to configure it?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the endpoint url?" The endpoint URL is one you provide at subscription creation. It would be an endpoint you have set up in some way that is reachable.

Comment: I mean how it gets generated? I was trying to create a push type subscription using console and it's asking one.. I am totally new to this so was just trying my luck.

Comment: You'd need to set up a webserver that has a URL associated with it or an [AppEngine endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) to process messages. If you don't already have an endpoint to process messages and don't have a specific reason to use the push model, then just stick to using the [pull model via the client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull).

Comment: Same question or confusion from where or how we can create the endpoint url

Comment: 1. Go on left bar choose cloud function 
2. Click on create new function
3. On the add form there is field "Trigger Type" it should be "cloud pub/sub"
4. When you select "cloud pub/sub" it will auto display list of topics
5. Choose the topic and complete and deploy the function
6. It will automatically create subscription for the topic @KamalAboul-Hosn

Comment: @Nisha  Go to Google Cloud Console and create/select a project.
On the header, click to open the menu and select ‘Pub/Sub’, or click https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/list 
Create/select a topic.
Add the service account google-play-developer-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com, and grant it the role of Pub/Sub Publisher.
Create a subscription. There are 2 types of subscription: 
Push: Similar to ios, the notification is sent to the endpoint we configure. (Here you need to create an endpoint on your backend server.)